# How to compile dependencies using cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake, dependencies, build-process

Given that I have the following file structure,

```
my_project
    CMakeLists.txt
    /include
        ...headers
    /src
        ...source files
    /vendor
        /third-party-project1
            CMakeLists.txt
        /third-party-project2
            CMakeLists.txt
```

How do I use the third party projects by compiling them according to their CMakeLists.txt files from my own CMake file? I specifically need their include dirs, and potentially any libs they have.

Furthermore, how could I use FIND_PACKAGE to test if the third party projects are installed in the system, and if they don't compile and link against the included ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find a project you may use [`find_package()`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/command/find_package.html) command. Hope your third party projects provide a corresponding finder module, otherwise you ought to write it. Then you may analyze a result of `find_package()` in your `CMakeLists.txt` and conditionally use `add_subdirectory()` to dive into `third-party-projectN/` -- this will build that libs as a part of your package. To use their headers just add (conditionally) `include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/third-party-projectN/include)`. Their libraries will be accessible from your `CMakeLists.txt` as "ordinal" targets.

If that packages already installed in your system, a finder module should provide you some variables to use for `include_directories()` and/or `target_link_libraries()`.

Comment: Ok this is helpful, but suppose the third party project doesn't provide a finder module. Is there some way to generate this easily, given that it is a CMake project? I know I can make the third party project export some targets with an auto-generated finder module, but that only works *after* building the project. To do what the OP wants the finder module has to exist *before* the project is built.

Comment: @BenFarmer, it mostly depends on the way the mentioned third-parties have installed _before_ you are going to build _your_ project w/ _included alternative sources_... Anyway, the answer to this question would be little bit bigger than a comment here %)

Comment: But the third party projects *aren't* installed first. Isn't that the whole point of the OP question? He wants to build them via his own project.

Comment: When he doesn't need any _finders_ ... as I respond, they'll be parts of his project and their libraries would be "visible" naturally